# Posting HTTP request with C# HTTPClient

Tags: c#, post, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to post a request to login to a webpage.

The original POST request

[image]

The original POST request part 2

[image]

I haven't done POST requests before. I'm using the following code for testing.
I'm trying to figure out the body of the request.

```
public async void PostRequest()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "loginForm", "loginForm" },
            { "userName385076574", "005847951" },
            { "password908645299", "Password" },
            { "javax.faces.ViewState", "e1s1"},
            { "as_sfid", "?" },
            { "as_fid", "?"},
            { "j_idt26", "?" }
        };

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "C# App");
        //  client.
        var response = await client.PostAsync("https://gkmpay.oberthur.com/mui/mwallet/webTerminal?execution=e1s2", content);

        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

Please can someone tell me what "as_sfid", "as_fid", and "j_idt26" are? And how I can go about posting these values along with the other values I have already set. I have examined in fiddler and noticed they change each request. A google search suggests it may have something to do with Citrix? Though i'm not sure. Hoping someone can shed some light.

Comment: First off, `async void` is a bad idea.  It should be `async Task` or even better `async Task<someType>`.

Comment: Those fields are inserted by the Citrix Netscaler application firewall to prevent cross-site request forgery attacks, which is basically what your POST request is (as seen from the Netscaler's point of view).  You cannot spoof those values.

Comment: Ahh, good to know. I will make note of this for if i ever overcome this problem :). Thank you.

@HaukurHaf Ahh, I had feared it was something like that. Thank you for enlightening me.

Comment: They are probably fields that the client received and should sent them back, and sometimes the client allowed them to be manipulated. So after getting those fields from the previous post response send them back, if you didn't get them from the first post response, then you should do a get? request first to accept all fields and then send them on every request.